# "Interactive" Sleep in C++

Tags: c++, winapi

I started to learn c++ a while ago. I done a lot of console program with Visual Studio 2010 and now I want to make win32 programs. I read a lot of tutorial and I understand the basics now.

I made a button which call another function. The function is doing great everything working. But there are Sleep(x) in this function and the GUI isn't responding while the Sleep doesn't end. The function is done in 60 sec because there is a lot of Sleep in it but it is do everything what is should just do GUI isn't responding this time.

I think I know the source of this problem. In my opinion the problem is Sleep totally pause the application (Windows say: not responding).

How can I make a Sleep/pause which doesn't freeze the GUI? Is there a function or I must do it in a totally different way?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Is the Sleep call really needed? Does your function really need to "**do nothing** for a certain amount of time"? If so, please tell us why. That will surely help you get better answers.

Comment: If the function does something periodic, consider using a WM_TIMER message.

Comment: I try to make a World of Warcraft auto loginer. It's little brother (a console application) works good. (This version too except the GUI freeze).

My method is the following: from an ini file it get the user name/password. It launch the wow.exe but while wow loading it doesn't have to do anything. So it sleeps about 8 sec. After it copy user name to clipboard and "press" ctrl+v and so on.

I know this isn't the best method but That is what I could do. And I only do programs like this to learn. That is Why I asked this question, too. :)

Comment: "I know this isn't the best method but That is what I could do." If it works, I think this is an excellent solution. However, note that hardcoded timing is difficult on different PCs: the time to start WoW on each computer depends on a lot of factors (performance, other programs running, etc.)

Comment: I know.
I make it to be changeable in the ini file so you can select have many sec to wait.
The console brother just great, but thanks to the help of the community the GUI will be more greater. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> In my opinion the problem is Sleep totally pause the application

Yes.

> How can I make a Sleep/pause which doesn't freeze the GUI?

Why do you need to sleep in the first place? If the function is misbehaving, you can always run it in a background thread (but be aware that this adds quite a bit of complexity and difficulty). Normally, you shouldn't need to sleep at all. If you do have to sleep, then make it a loop that spins until enough time passes, processing the events from the OS and calling `Sleep(0)` which yields the timeslice.

Comment: Since the OP is new to Win32, it's worth mentioning that `Sleep` does not pause the application, but rather the thread it was called from. On the said case it's effectively the same, but if takes your advise and uses another thread, only one will be paused by the `Sleep`.

Comment: @eran: I'm a bit sleepy myself, so feel free to edit and clarify.

Comment: I see. So all I have to do is to run those codes in the background thread while the main thread (the GUI) can work and the background can sleep. Or am I understand it bad?

But yeah it is difficult but I currently looking for the easiest way to do this.

Comment: @Gaboros It is a common practice to let the GUI thread do only GUI work, and use another thread (or more) for the program logic. It does make it a bit harder, because you have to sometimes synchronize the two.

Comment: I see. I'm sure in my case it doesn't need synchronization but currently I'm just learning how to "send" my code to an other thread. :)

Comment: Ok, I found the easiest way to do this. This is just ... fantastic! :D
While I was just working with console application I have never thought it is possible to make things like this. I understand everything know, thanks for everyone who helped! :)

Answer (score 1):

Can you break your code into sections and use timers instead of Sleep?  That will keep the message pump running.  Look at this article in MSDN on using timers:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644901%28v=VS.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Either offload the work to a separate thread (see `CreateThread`) or, use `PeekMessage` et. al in a tight loop to process window messages and keep the GUI alive.

Of course you should ask yourself whether you really need to sleep. As you said, a sleep in the main thread (the thread that polls the message pump) prevents any GUI processing.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use threads. Remember that if you have a long-running process in your GUI, you have to create a thread and let it deal with all of your code—which in this case contains many sleep instructions. Once the thread finishes its job, it will notify you and you can then extract data from it.